# Binary tree implementation gives me segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to access data stored in my TreeNode. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NodeTag{
    int value;
    struct NodeTag *LLink;
    struct NodeTag *RLink;
} TreeNode;

void inOrder(TreeNode * n){
    if(n->LLink != NULL)
        inOrder(n->LLink);
    printf("%d ", n->value);
    if(n->RLink != NULL)
        inOrder(n->RLink);
}

void newNode(TreeNode * n, int v){
    n = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    n->value = v;
    n->LLink = NULL;
    n->RLink = NULL;
}

void addValue(TreeNode * r, int value){

    if(value < r->value){
        if(r->LLink == NULL){
            newNode(r->LLink, value);
        } else {
            addValue(r->LLink, value);
        }
    } else if (value > r->value) {
        if(r->RLink == NULL){
            newNode(r->RLink, value);
        } else {
            addValue(r->RLink, value);
        }
    }
}



int main(){

    TreeNode * root = 0;
    newNode(root, 1);
    printf("%d\n", root->value); //<--This is where I get the fault
    //addValue(root, 3);
    //addValue(root, 10);
    //addValue(root, 2);

    //inOrder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can explain to me why I'm getting this error it would be greatly appreciated. I'm a student learning C and I'm not too familiar with pointers and such.

Comment: The newNode() function doesn't do what you think it does. Change it to return a new node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void newNode(TreeNode * n, int v){
    n = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    n->value = v;
    n->LLink = NULL;
    n->RLink = NULL;
}
```

In this code, `n` is a pointer to a `TreeNode` struct but if you assign something to `n`, this is not visible outside of the function as the pointer is passed by value.

```
void writeToA ( int a ) {
    a = 5;
}

int main ( ) {
    int x = 10;
    writeToA(x)
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

What will this code print? It will print `10`, not `5`. That's because the value of `x` is passed to the function, not a reference to `x`. Changing that value within the function will not change the value of `x` outside the function.

A pointer is also a value, basically it is an int and the int value is a memory address:

```
void writeToPtr1 ( int * a ) {
    int i = 10;
    a = &i; // `a` now points to the memory address of i
}

void writeToPtr2 ( int * a ) {
    *a = 5; // This doesn't change where `a` points to,
    // it writes 5 to the memory address to that `a` points to.   
}

int main ( ) {
    int x = 10;
    int *ptr = &x; // ptr now points to the memory address of x!
    writeToPtr1(ptr);
    // ptr still points to the memory address of x!
    // As not a reference to ptr was passed, the memory
    // address of x was passed to the function!

    writeToPtr2(ptr);
    // ptr still points to the memory address of x!
    // But this memory now has the value 5 and not 10 anymore.
}
```

You need to return the result of the allocation:

```
TreeNode * newNode ( int v ) {
    TreeNode * n = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    n->value = v;
    n->LLink = NULL;
    n->RLink = NULL;
    return n;
}

int main ( ) {
    TreeNode * root = newNode(1);
    printf("%d\n", root->value);
    return 0;
}
```

Or you need to pass a reference to the pointer and then change the value the pointer points to:

```
 void newNode ( TreeNode ** outNode, int v ) {
    // TreeNode ** is a pointer to a pointer to a TreeNode!
    TreeNode * n = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    n->value = v;
    n->LLink = NULL;
    n->RLink = NULL;
    *outNode = n; // Make the pointer point to `n`
}

int main ( ) {
    TreeNode * root = NULL;
    newNode(&root, 1); // Pass a pointer to root
    printf("%d\n", root->value);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`newNode` shall either return a pointer to allocated memory or you can send double pointer to the function and allocate memory there.

```
TreeNode* newNode(int v){
    TreeNode *new_node = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));

    n->value = v;
    n->LLink = NULL;
    n->RLink = NULL;

    return new_node
}
```

or

```
void newNode(TreeNode ** n, int v){
    *n = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    (*n)->value = v;
    (*n)->LLink = NULL;
    (*n)->RLink = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C arguments are passed by value. Calling `newNode(r->LLink, value)` will therefore not modify `r->LLink`.

Consider this simple function:

```
void Foo(int x)
{
  x = x * 2 ;
}
```

Will calling `Foo(n)` multiply n by 2 ? No.

You would either need this:

```
void Foo(int *x)
{
  *x = *x * 2 ;
}
```

and call `Foo(&n);`

or:

```
void Foo(int x)
{
  return x * 2 ;
}
```

and call `n = Foo(n);`